# error saying system.void cannot be used from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, compiler-errors

I have a interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Guestbook.Models;

namespace Guestbook.Controllers
{
    public interface IGuestbookRepository
    {
        IList<GuestbookEntry> GetMostRecentEntries();
        GuestbookEntry FindById(int id);
        IList<CommentSummary> GetCommentSummary();
        Void AddEntry(GuestbookEntry entry);
    }
}
```

and the implementation class looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Guestbook.Models;

namespace Guestbook.Controllers
{
public class GuestbookRepository : IGuestbookRepository
{
    private readonly GuestbookContext _db = new GuestbookContext();

     public void AddEntry(GuestbookEntry entry)
     {
        entry.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;

        _db.Entries.Add(entry);
        _db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

when i type to compile it i get error saying
System.void cannot be used from c# -- use typeof(void) to get the void type object.

What exactly is wrong that I'm doing? Can someone help me maybe?

Comment: The case is not correct in `Void AddEntry(GuestbookEntry entry);`. `void` should be lowercase.

Comment: In future, please show *where* the error message occurs.

Comment: yes which line is the error reported on?

Comment: it was on interface where  Void AddEntry(GuestbookEntry entry); is located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem, in the interface declaration:

```
Void AddEntry(GuestbookEntry entry);
```

It should be:

```
void AddEntry(GuestbookEntry entry);
```

The first version refers to the [`System.Void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) type, which can't be used within C# (as per the error message). The second is the C# way of writing a method which no return value.

Answer (score 3):

The case is not correct in `Void AddEntry(GuestbookEntry entry);`. `void` should be lowercase.